# Mongoose: how to set a schema-field to be the ID?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Given the following schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   , email   :  { type: String }
   , passwordHash   :  { type: String }
   , roles  :  { type: [String] }
});
```

I'd like `email` to be the key. 
How can I define this?

I could do:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
       , _id:  { type: String }
       , passwordHash   :  { type: String }
       , roles  :  { type: [String] }
    });
```

so MongoDB would recognize it as the id-field, and adapt my code to refer to `_id` instead of `email` but that doesn't feel clean to me.

Anyone?

Comment: I think you're better off leaving _id as an ObjectID and making email a unique index.

Comment: Is that the general consensus? Having domain-Id's as Unique and let MongoDB take care of the technical Id's?

Comment: Since you're using Mongoose, another option would be to use the email string as the _id field and then add a [virtual field](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/virtuals.html) named "email" that returned the _id to clean up the code that uses the email.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Since you're using Mongoose, one option is to use the email string as the `_id` field and then add a [virtual field](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) named `email` that returns the `_id` to clean up the code that uses the email.

```js
var userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String},
    passwordHash: {type: String},
    roles: {type: [String]}
});

userSchema.virtual('email').get(function() {
    return this._id;
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

User.findOne(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc.email);
});
```

Note that a virtual field is not included by default when converting a Mongoose doc to a plain JS object or JSON string. To include it you have to set the `virtuals: true` option in the [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) or [`toJSON()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON) call:

```js
var obj = doc.toObject({ virtuals: true });
var json = doc.toJSON({ virtuals: true });
```

Comment: In order to make the answer more complete, i added more details about virtual fields - seems to be common question.

Comment: Looks like that edit was rejected @SmartyTwiti.  The concept is good though so I incorporated that info.  Thanks.