# Can MongoDB accept custom Objectid that exceeds 12 bytes and 24 hex characters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I have multiple ID's in mongoDB that looked like this:

```
"_id" : "SunnyEntertainment_LanternFestival_Boothposter_20180912223112"

"_id" : "GlobalEnterprise_ThanksGiving_childrentoys_20181022222228"

"_id" : "SuperCompany_NewYearEvent_partylightstick_20181231211112"
```

After I ran node.js and connect it to localhost, it gives me the error of

```
 Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

I kind of know that it is due to the ID that exceeds 12 bytes or 24 hex characters, but I would like to keep them as it is easier for me to keep track with the data and easy to identify them instead of random numbers when looking at the database.

Is there any possible way of removing the limit of just 12 bytes and 24 hex characters?

I've heard that I need to modify and create my own objectid library for that but I don't know how many files will be affected by creating and include my own library. Are there any alternatives to this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I am migrating from Firebase so I already know how to generate the ID.

This is different from the link [Mongoose: how to set a schema-field to be the ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352900/mongoose-how-to-set-a-schema-field-to-be-the-id)

My problem is not how to generate an ID but how to remove the 12bytes and 24 hex characters limit so that I can freely use how long or how big the size of the ID that I pleases. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post, the original post did not answer my question.

Comment: It's not any different at all. The problem is evident in your error message and the data you are providing. Mongoose is attempting to cast that string as an `ObjectId`. That **cannot** happen. What you can do is tell your mongoose schema that you actually want a string in place. This is what the answer actually shows you how to do. Which also means this is a "mongoose" thing, and nothing to do with MongoDB itself, which does not care what type the `_id` key is.